# Multiple map() calls in an Angular 6 service

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an HTTP GET request that returns multiple objects that I want to turn into multiple observables.  Here is an example of the response:

```
{
    lookup1: 
    [
      {
        "label": "lookup1 option 1",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "lookup1 option 2",
        "value": 2
      }
    ],
    lookup2: 
    [
      {
        "label": "lookup2 option 1",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "lookup2 option 2",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
}
```

Here is my service that gets two observables:

```
this.lookup1 = this.apiService.get('/lookups/')
  .pipe(map(response => response["lookup1"]));
this.lookup2 = this.apiService.get('/lookups/')
  .pipe(map(response => response["lookup2"]));
```

How do I do this with one HTTP GET request?

### EDIT

Note that code like this will do 2 HTTP GET requests:

```
let lookups = this.apiService.get('/lookups/');
this.lookup1 = lookups
  .pipe(map(response => response["lookup1"]));
this.lookup2 = lookups
  .pipe(map(response => response["lookup2"]));
```

Comment: `that returns multiple objects` - how many objects we are talking here?  Also, if there are 100 objects - how are you planning to expose those 100 observables to its consumers - what is the goal here?

Comment: The goal is to get all lookups the application will need from one API call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

Create 2 subjects that will be updated once the request resolves.

```
let map1 = new Subject();
let map2 = new Subject();

this.lookup1 = map1.pipe(map(response => response["lookup1"]));
this.lookup2 = map2.pipe(map(response => response["lookup2"]));

this.apiService.get('/lookups/').subscribe( response => { 
   map1.next(response);
   map2.next(response);
})
```

**Method 2**

You can use `concatMap` and `from` to transform a stream into another.

```
this.apiService.get('/lookups/').pipe(
  concatMap( responseJson => from(Object.values(responseJson)))
).subscribe( arrayElement=> console.log(arrayElement))
```

Output :

```
// first object emitted : 
[
  {
    "label": "lookup1 option 1",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "lookup1 option 2",
    "value": 2
  }
]

// second object emitted :

[
  {
    "label": "lookup2 option 1",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "lookup2 option 2",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

**concatMap** 
takes an Observable and emits another Observable.

**from**
transforms an iterable element into a stream. You'll get as much emissions as items in the iterable.

Comment: Where is the assignment to observables `this.lookup1` and `this.lookup2`?

Comment: @Jess I edited `Method 1` and inserted `this.lookup1` and `this.lookup2`

Comment: Thank you!  It works and it completely blows my mind, but I think I understand that `map` returns an observable, so it can do the assignment "before" the GET request happens.  I have chosen **Method 1** which seems more readable...?